# Text field cuts off last character

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

so I have a `TextField` and a `SecureField`, and both will randomly cut off the last character:

```
TextField("email address", text: $userInfo.email)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.buttonText)
            }.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).padding().padding(.top, 50)
```

and

```
 SecureField("password", text: $userInfo.password)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.buttonText)
            }.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).padding()
```

for example, if I entered my email as `test@gmail.com` and my password as `password123`, my print statements in other parts of the code would say `test@gmail.co` and `password12`.

It also says

> Binding action tried to update multiple times per frame.

any time I type a key, this might be related. I have only tested on simulators.

edit:
user class

```
class User: ObservableObject{
var id = UUID()
var email : String
var password : String
@Published var loggedIn : Bool 
@Published var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "user")!

init(email: String = "", loggedIn : Bool = false, password : String = ""){
       self.email = email
       self.loggedIn = loggedIn
       self.password = password
   }
```

it is an environment object, if that affects it at all.

Comment: Could you please provide your `userInfo` Model so that I can assist you further?

Comment: @geethsg7 I just edited it

Comment: Any luck with this?  I am facing the same issue

Comment: Me too this is a major issue. All previous Apps made with 8.6.1 on Montery all good. UPgrade to Sonoma with 8.6.5 for Xcode 15 as per Apple SDK upgrade to 17.2 and now all textfields broken. Nightmare.